# cannot find symbol - out of bounds error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a class assignment. Basically, we must use one-dimensional arrays to display a student's name, his current grade, and the subject. Code follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class sortStudents {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
        int numofstudents = input.nextInt();
        String[] names = new String[numofstudents];
        int[] array = new int[numofstudents];
        String[] subject = new String[numofstudents];
        for(int i = 0; i < numofstudents; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the student's name: ");
            names[i] = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the student's score: ");
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the subject: ");
            subject[i] = input.next();
        }
        selectionSort(names, array, subject);
        System.out.println(names[i] + array[i] + subject[i]);

    }
    public static void selectionSort(String[] names, int[] array, String[] subject) {
        for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            String temp;
            String classTemp = " ";
            int currentMax = array[0];
            int currentMaxIndex = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (currentMax > array[j]) {
                    currentMax = array[j];
                    currentMaxIndex = j;
                }
            }       
                if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
                    temp = names[currentMaxIndex];
                    names[currentMaxIndex] = names[i];
                    names[i] = temp;
                    array[currentMaxIndex] = array[i];
                    array[i] = currentMax;
                    subject[currentMaxIndex] = subject[i];
                    subject[i] = classTemp;
                }
        }       
    }
}
```

The error is produced while compiling at line 22. I'm thinking it's due to the variable "i" not being initialized outside the loop. But when I place the variable "i" outside the loop, I get an array out of bounds error. Any help to fix this would be greatly appreciated :)

P.S. I'm new to this site, so I apologize if I've posted incorrectly.

Comment: You should **always** post the stack trace. `for(int i = array.length - 1` what happens if `array.length` is 0?

Comment: You need to iterate over those arrays again to print the content.

Comment: When you place the `i` outside the loop, note that it is equal to `numofstudents` when you exit the loop.

I assume that you want to print out all the information, in which case Rohit is correct. Otherwise, you can modify the index as need be.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do on line 22? Print all of the arrays?

Comment: @m0skit0: As far as I can tell the program simply closes if set the array = 0                                                         Thanks for the help so far! The additional for loop solved the issue. Sometimes I feel like I might never figure this stuff out.

Comment: *"Sometimes I feel like I might never figure this stuff out."* I can assure you you're not the only one that has had that feeling :)

Comment: glad the issue is solved! also, when an answer has been useful or helpful to you, it's customary on stackoverflow to upvote or accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

when you do this:

```
System.out.println(names[i] + array[i] + subject[i]);
```

the `i` variable does not exist, as its located directly after the for loop, where it does exist.

what you could do is just put another for loop around it:

```
for(int p =0; p < numOfStudents; p++)
{
 System.out.println(names[p] + array[p] + subject[p]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you get to `System.out.println(names[i] + array[i] + subject[i]);` there is no `i` variable in scope.

1. If you are trying to print the info each time it is entered, put that code inside of your existing `for` loop.
2. If you are trying to print the sorted list at the end, you will need to make another `for` loop with another variable to run through the arrays.

   ```
   for(int j = 0; j < numOfStudents; j++) {
       System.out.println(names[i] + array[i] + subject[i]);
   }
   ```

Comment: if your loop iterator in this answer is j then it should read System.out.println(names[j] + array[j] + subject[j]);